# insert into from where condition on both tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I want to feed `table1 name` with `table2 name` based on the reference I have on my `table1` in my `table2` (`id`).

How can I achieve this? something like:

```
insert into table1 (name)
  select name from table2
  where table2.id = table1.table2Id;
```

The `where` clause is not aware of `table1` and cannot apply the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a FROM-clause (with JOINs) in your INSERT..SELECT queries, but also in your UPDATE and/or DELETE queries.

If you want to insert new records into table1 based on data from table2, you may only need to make sure that there will not be attempted to insert data in table1 that might break any constraints.

The WHERE-clause in your example INSERT-query might not be valid in that case, since it seems to assume that there are already matching records in table1. (There might be possible exceptional scenarios that would justify such a query, but I will not elaborate on those scenarios here, since your question does not indicate that that's relevant in your case.)

Example for inserting records in table1 based on (related) data in table1 and table2:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name)
SELECT table2.name
FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON table1.[ref] = table2.[ref] --use some sensible relation logic between table1 and table2 here
WHERE ... --check for valid data here
```

If you want to update existing records in table1 with data from table2, you can probably use an UPDATE query instead of an INSERT-query. Again, you should check that you do not attempt to update data that would break any constraints.

Example for updating records in table1 that match with data in table2:

```
UPDATE table1
SET name = table2.name
FROM table2 
WHERE table2.id = table1.id --or use some other sensible relation logic between table1 and table2 here (together with other validation logic)
```

You might also use a FROM-clause in your UPDATE query, but it seems you must be careful not to include the target table in that FROM-clause and supply the correct join with the target table records in the WHERE-clause.

Comment: Do **NOT** repeat the target table in the FROM clause of the UPDATE statement in Postgres.

Comment: Does it work with an alias then? How else can you join the dataset of the FROM clause to the target table?

Comment: You just join in the where clause: `update t1 ... from t2 where t1.id = t2.id`